# Suppose $n$ chords are drawn in a given circle at random. Find the probability that there shall be $1$ intersection

Tags: probability

**Question**:- Suppose $n$ chords are drawn in a given circle at random. Prove that the probability that there shall be $1$ intersection is $\frac{2^n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n-2)!}$.

Yesterday while doing questions on probability I got stuck on this problem. I couldn't find any way of starting this problem since only variable here is $n$ and we may have to assume some parameters like radius.

Can anybody help me!!

Comment: Well, just to get started.  With four points $\{p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ chosen randomly on a circle, we may assume the chords $\overline{p_0p_1}$ and $\overline{p_2p_3}$, without loss of generality.  Place $p_0$ at the origin.  Now randomly place the other points on the circle.  There are 6 possibilities.  Of these, two orderings will have the chords intersect.  So for $n=2,$ $p=1/3.$

Comment: If they are truly at random, the probability that they meet at one point is zero, obviously. So there must be other restrictions: Chords between $n$ vertices of a regular $n$-gon, ...

Comment: @vonbrand I don't think that interpretation is correct.  I'm interpretating the question as: any pair of chords could be non-intersecting or intersect at a point on the closed disc, and the total number of intersections over all pairs is 1.  Ofc course that still leaves open the question "what is a random chord".

Comment: @user10354138 I'm interpreting a random chord to be a chord drawn between two randomly selected points on the circle.